# Why can't I create a database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I can't seem to create a mongoDB database. I've read like 4 tutorials, and it seems like it should be pretty straight forward. Did I miss anything? Could I have a problem with my installation or something?

```
> use a
switched to db a
> a.abc.save({abc:"asdf"})
2015-04-17T01:39:45.723-0400 E QUERY    ReferenceError: a is not defined
at (shell):1:1
> a.abc.insert({abc:"asdf"})
2015-04-17T01:39:58.572-0400 E QUERY    ReferenceError: a is not defined
at (shell):1:1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
a.abc.save({abc:"asdf"})
```

Write

```
db.abc.save({abc:"asdf"})
```

When you use the command

```
use a
```

You make the system refer to the database `a`, which can be accessed using the keyword `db`. Please refer to the [Getting Started With the Mongo Shell Guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/).